# What flash game is this from?

Tags: game-identification, flash

What is this image from? Is it Thing Thing Arena? There were so many of these kinds of games on Addictinggames.com when I was a teenager.

[image: this image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a Flash animation, and not a game itself

Comment: @pinckerman But Sometimes a user thinks this is a game.

Comment: @Fmbalbuena doesn't matter what OP thinks, but what actually is.

Comment: *[Comments deleted]* - Let's keep this civil please, remember the [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) applies. If you disagree with a person's actions, debate the points they raise instead. If you want the broader community to review actions taken, please raise it on [meta], although it's worth noting that as of writing, the question is at 1 close vote, and has [passed through the review system](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/close/316889) and remained open.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is from a Flash *animation*, not a Flash game. Specifically, it's from [SACRIFICE.fla](https://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/707265), an instalment in the *Madness Combat* series. The screenshot is cropped from the opening scene, in which the protagonist Deimos is freefalling through

> the afterlife, following his death in an earlier instalment.

*Madness Interactive* is also part of the *Madness Combat* series, so I can understand why Bassie thought that was the answer, but *Madness Interactive* came out in 2003 and predates Deimos' debut by several years.

(Content warning: SACRIFICE.fla contains extreme graphic violence and disturbing imagery.)

Answer (score 11):

Looks like [Madness Interactive](https://madnesscombat.fandom.com/wiki/Madness_Interactive) - I used to love that game, thanks for reminding me about it!

[Newgrounds link](https://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/118826)

**As pointed out by F1Krazy, its actually from some Madness animation, not the Madness Interactive game**

Comment: Nothing unclear about this answer. It gives a link to the wiki and to the actual game, both of which are correct.

Comment: It's from the Madness series, but it's not *Madness Interactive*.